# Simple C++ programme; can't seem to get it right

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class CompanyName
{
public:

    char name[10];

    void display()
    {
        if(name=="emily")
            cout<<"Hired!"<<endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    CompanyName c;

    cout<<"enter name"<<endl;
    cin>>c.name;

    c.display();

    getch();
}
```

So my friend just got placed in a company and I want to congratulate her (and announce that so-and-so company hired her) on her facebook wall, using a small CPP programme. I don't want to just print 'congratulations Emily!' because I already did that for something else. So this time you can see what I want to do if you just look at the code. Any better suggestions are highly welcome.
But my problem here is, I can't get this code to run. I feel like the 'if' line is not right. Can someone please correct the code for me? I'm still a beginner.

Comment: If you are going to deal with strings you should use a `std::string`.

Comment: What does `I can't get this code to run` mean? What happens?

Comment: You cannot compare name to "emiky" it will never be true. Since yiu use c++ turn name into a string and comparison will work.

Comment: Well, it just asks me to 'enter name' and then nothing happens until I exit. The if condition doesn't work.
And noted, NathanOliver. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, does that make a difference?

Comment: How do you turn it into a string?

Comment: @Cersei You cannot apply the `==` equality test operator using a raw char array, either use `strcmp()` or change `name`'s type to `std::string`.

Comment: Would like to point out the elephant in the room, `conio` is not a standard header. Stop using it.

Comment: First, perepare yourself psychologically to live without `<conio>` because it's not standard C++ and certainly a legacy from the past.   Then if you include `<string>`, use them for example in `string name;`.  Finally, could you clarify your expectations: do you really expect an answer with network code for posting on FB ? What else could you print than "congratulations" ?  Where shall the text come from ?  Is Emily the only employee of a company ?

Comment: @Thebluefish and what about `void main`?

Comment: @Thebluefish: You can't make very interesting programs if you only stick to standard headers.

Comment: emily is the name of the company?

Comment: @Benjamin but one should try not use very old headers from old compilers from another era on new projects unless there is a purpose to it, as in to maintain legacy applications

Comment: Why is void main() inappropriate? You have to put return 0 at the end if you use int main() anyway, right? I'm probably way off mark since I don't fully understand everything.
@Christophe I get your point about where the text will come from, but I don't wanna do the print thing. I'm going to make this in a .png format once I write everything. And yes, I certainly expect an answer regardless of where I use the code. I have valid doubts.

Comment: @Cersei look at http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main . But now i'm lost: first tou want to post on facebook (which would require networking+complex apis) then you want to generate a png (graphic file). I'd suggest One step at a time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You declared `name` as `char name[10];`, then `name` is going to be treated as a pointer. Your pointer is never going to be equal to the string `"emily"`.

Solution: It is highly recommended to simply use the great `std::string` from `#include <string>`

This should work (since you included the library already):

```
class CompanyName
{
public:
    std::string name;

    // ..
        if (name == "emily")
           // cout
    // ..
};
```

Comment: You're welcome, but don't forget to propose the solution, even if it's already in the other answers.

Comment: Done. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `name` just using `==` operator, as it is a `char` array, you should use `strcmp(name, "emily") == 0`

Better yet, use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class to store and manipulate strings, with `std::string`, you can simply compare it using `==` operator.

Another thing: You should not use `getch()` as it is not standard c++.

Comment: So I should use getchar(); instead?

Comment: You're using `getch()`, just to stop your screen for a while?

Comment: No, to get the output on the screen.

Comment: `cout` gets the output to the screen, `getch()` just make your program wait for a while, untill you press some key to continue (`getch()` can be used to take input, but it's not recommended to use it).

Comment: But you can always use `cin.get()` for this purpose too, (It'll stop too, untill you press **Enter** key)

Comment: Right, yeah! But won't the program exit immediately after displaying the output if I don't use getch()? I want the program to wait until the user is done checking the output.

Comment: Thanks! cin.get(), got it.

Answer (score 1):

You know, if you used `std::string`, this code would be easier. See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CompanyName {
public:
    string name;

    void display()
    {
        if (name == "emily")
            cout << "Hired!" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CompanyName c;

    cout << "enter name" << endl;
    cin >> c.name;

    c.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Then here there is no limit to the size of your string. By the way, your code doesn't work because it can only contain 9 characters, + `\0`, which means that your string would be too long. Use the solution above.
<kbd>[Live Example](http://cpp.sh/2vcd)</kbd>

Comment: I did not know you could use 'string name'. We've only been taught to use a char array in CPP (but we did use strings in C). I think I remember my teacher saying you can't? use 'string' in CPP but it might be that I misunderstood...Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe in C++ to directly compare a character array with a string. As the others have suggested, try using `std::string`, it will handle all the background stuff for you.

Here's a fun example using your class's destructor:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class CompanyName
{
public:
    std::string name;
    ~CompanyName()
    {
        if (name == "emily")
            cout << "Hired!" << endl;
        else cout << "Who's that?" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CompanyName c;
    cout << "Enter new employee name" << endl;
    cin >> c.name;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile online: http://cpp.sh/433h7

Comment: Making it *even more* misleading.

Comment: Thanks so much, this helps a lot! I am left with a few queries though, such as why did you use a destructor and not a constructor? And isn't EXIT_SUCCESS not an int value?

Comment: @Thebluefish Misleading?

Comment: @Cersei For someone just starting C++, it's better to go over best practices. A destructor-based method for doing standard stuff is frankly mis-leading.

Comment: @Cersei, this solution doesn't fall under best practices, but it still is amusing. C++ follows an idiom called [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), which essentially translates to how long C++ maintains variables in scope. When the program comes to the `return` keyword, the variables in scope are destroyed, so the `CompanyName` destructor runs automatically at that point - this is when the name is checked and printed. EXIT_SUCCESS is a macro defined in `stdlib`, and it resolves to the proper `int` for successful termination.